# How can I prohibit to Windows7 to turn off my HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, msata

I have a notebook: ThinkPad Edge E530. I have just installed a new mSATA drive. The OS is installed on the mSATA drive, and the data are stored on the HDD. While using the computer (browsing etc.) I hear that my HDD turns off, after a few seconds it turns on. I set the "Turn off hard disk after" property to "Never" is every power options, but it did not help. 
Any idea?

Comment: are you sure its the drive powering down and not a fan?

Comment: Im sure that the HDD turns off

Comment: Is it windows which turns the drive off or the drive itself which decides to go to sleep mode, without OS intervention? (If it is a so called 'green' drive then this is likely).  Normally I would suggest [hdparm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) to check the value for the `-S sleep_value` for this, but that tool is not available in windows.

Comment: Yep, as @Hennes stated I'd first confirm that it's not the drive's own firmware that's responsible. If that's the case, the manufacturer *might* have a utility available to disable this "feature".